# jQuery multi-select update on postback (SSRS)

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, reporting-services, reportviewer

Currently I use SSRS reports for a client that needs Excel and PDF export readily available. I also use jQuery multiselect dropdowns as report filters. For example, the first listbox/multiselect is populated on page load. Once it is selected, a listbox/multiselect is populated based off the values from the first listbox. Then a third might be populated after selections are made in the second list box. All of this is done with jQuery/ajax.

When generating the SSRS report, it posts back. The subsequent client-side listboxes (all but the first) will not retain their values automatically, so I store values to a hidden field then re-populate them into the dropdown.

This is okay for small amounts of data, but I would like a better solution (i.e. I would like the client side to just retain the data, but I doubt that is possible) for larger amounts of data in the dropdown. Sometimes our filters can contain thousands of options across multiple dropdowns.

I am using the Eric Hynds multiselect on a listbox, and it will retain the first multiselect options in the first listbox. However, once ajax has been used on the other listboxes I am forced to hide their selected values in hidden fields and re-write them back out to the listbox after postback. (I have also tried using dropdowns with far less success.)

Original multiselect (a listbox):

```
$("#lbExample").multiselect
```

Ajax is used to populate it:

```
$("#lbExample_div").html(msg.d)
```

Values user selected saved to hidden field in code behind:

```
hidExample.Value = "values"
```

Postback occurs when generating SSRS report

I check to see if postback occurred and then repopulate my multiselect by clicking the boxes:

```
if (isPostBack()) 
{
   for (i = 0; i < array_of_example.length; i++) 
      {
          $("#lbExample").multiselect("widget").find(":checkbox[value='" +               array_of_example[i] + "']").each(function () 
          {
              this.click();
            });
      }
 }
```

This works, but I am looking for a better way. Anyone else ever run into this and overcome it without using hidden fields or something like this? Anyone know why the multiselect retaings on the first listbox (where no ajax has been executed on it) but not on subsequent list boxes?

Comment: Could you explain how you are generating the report, and why it's causing a postback?

Comment: I am using the Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer class and this is how I add to the page element reportViewer (it is posting back because this code is on server-side click):  reportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("ReportName", method()));
            reportViewer.LocalReport.Refresh();
            reportViewer.ZoomMode = ZoomMode.Percent;
            reportViewer.Focus();

Comment: The only solution I can think of is to place your viewer and parameter controls in an ajax update panel this will make the remember options functionality less of a hassle with client side scripting. However, the net result will be the same. When your page is rendered after the postback you will have to either call a db function to get the parameterss or the response will have to provide them.